# How come when I render my animation in Blender the active cameras do not change like they do in the viewport?

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view, camera, marker

I have been using markers in the timeline and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>B</kbd> to change the active camera throughout my Blender animation. When I press play in the 3D viewport it changes the active camera at the markers as I want it to, but when I render the animation, the view stays on the first active camera and doesn't change.

Comment: pls provide example blend file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have *View* > *Local Camera* enabled in the *3D Viewport*. If this is the case, your animation will only be rendered from the camera which is selected there.

If you have a second *3D Viewport* where the option is disabled, then this viewport will correctly show the switching between cameras. Only the *Local Camera* viewport will use just one camera.

The strange thing however is, when I test it, as soon as I have a second viewport where the switching works, it works in rendering, too. So if my answer doesn't help we maybe need your file to investigate further.

[image: local camera]

Comment: My local camera setting was off on both viewports and it still doesn't change int he render.

Comment: Then maybe you should upload your file as Chris suggested if all settings should be correct for rendering...